# How to capture third-party JS library DOM changes using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm appending a third-party JavaScript library that is required by payment gateway I'm using. This library adds hidden inputs to form (with errors, code values, etc.) after submit. How can I capture HTML DOM changes caused by this library?

I tried to use document.getElementsByName on form submit, but it doesn't work. It seems that the third-party library HTML DOM change is executed after my onClick function and  I don't know what to do with that.

```
<input type="hidden" name="crazy_payment_gateway_error_name" value="2" />
```

Comment: The usual way is to wrap the third-party library to adapt it for React. Hard to tell you what you need to do when you don't post any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can use DOM Mutation observer.
It let you watch and inspect changed to your elements.

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Your callback will get into about changes to the DOM. Source code and more info on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: And that's going to plug in to React's data flow... where/how?

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @JaredSmith if it helps you, you can uptove and mark the answer as accepted by clicking the V.

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein think you meant that for simplecreator, who should definitely do so.

Comment: I upvoted it, but my reputation is too low (below 15 reputation you don't see one's upvote)

Comment: @simplecreator : To accept an answer you don't need reputation.